# Replace value of array when key match?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My actual code dont push the object when the key match , but how do i update the value of the key when it's match ?

```
this.state.data.concat(items).filter(function (a) {
    return !this[a.key] && (this[a.key] = true);
}, Object.create(null))
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet to reproduce your issue?

Comment: can you further explain what you're exactly trying to achive?

Comment: i try to update value of my array => this.state.data with .concat(items) , i want to concat but replace the existing value who have the same key

Answer (score 0):

```
// some object we want to change
const items = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
  v: true,
  g: true
};
// some value we want to match with object key
let someKeyWeWantToMatch = "b";
// for of loop
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) {
  // if key matches...
  if (key === someKeyWeWantToMatch) {
    // ...change its value
    items[key] = true;
  }
}
// and we are done
console.log(items);

/* 
EXPLANATION:
Objects are not iterable, so if we want to iterate throught them we have to make an Map out of them
We do this with: Object.entries(objectName)
So object goes from this:
{a:'aaa'}
Into this:
['a','aaa']

Then we can easily check the value of its key, and change it if we want.
 */
```